# Confusion in building sql query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks exactly like below

```
School              Course              Date             Status

SCH1            SCH1CRS1        2011-01-15           S

                SCH1CRS1        2011-01-17           C

SCH1            SCH1CRS2        2011-01-15           S

SCH2            SCH2CRS1        2011-01-15           S

                SCH2CRS1        2011-01-21           C

SCH2             SCH2CRS2        2011-01-22          S

               SCH2CRS2          2011-01-25          C
```

Status S=Started and C=Completed and date is start date and completed date. When a course started, user enters schoolID, courseID,Date and status, But when a course is completed, user enters courseID, Date and status. User does not enter SchoolID. From the table we can understand that SCH1CRS1 and SCH1CRS2 belongs to SCH1. What i need to know is, In a particular school, on a particular date, how many courses started but not completed.

You can see in SCH1, on 2011-01-15 two courses have started, but only one is completed. It doesn't matter when the course is completed. All i need to know is completed or not. In SCH2, two courses started on different dates, but both are completed.

Result table should be like this

```
Input Date: 2011-01-15

School             Not completed  

SCH1                       1

SCH2                       0

Input Date: 2011-01-22

School           Not Completed

SCH2                      0
```

I think this is a messy table and database design rules are not followed. But this is what i have . No option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the completed course related to the started course, and if there is no completed course, count 1.

```
SELECT startedCourse.School AS School, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN completedCourse IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotCompleted
FROM MyTable startedCourse
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable completedCourse
        ON startedCourse.Status = 'S'
        AND completedCourse.Status = 'C'
        AND startedCourse.Course = completedCourse.Course
WHERE startedCourse.Date = ?
GROUP BY startedCourse.School
```

Answer (score 0):

from the top of my head :

```
select c_started.courseID, c_started.courseDate as StartDate, c_completed.courseDate as CompletedDate, 
case 
 when c_completed.courseDate IS NULL then 'incomplete'
 Else 'completed'
end as courseStatus
from tbCourses as c_started
left join tbCourses as c_completed on c_started.courseID = c_completed.courseID 
and c_started.courseDate < c_completed.courseDate
where c_started.Status = 'S'
```

Would give you something like the following :

courseID -- StartDate -- CompletedDate --   courseStatus

course1 -- 2010-01-12 -- 2010-02-25      --  completed

course2 -- 2011-01-21 -- NULL            --  incomplete

course3 -- 2010-10-15 -- NULL            --  incomplete

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
declare @InputDate datetime = '20110115';

with cCourseList as (

select  t1.School, t1.Course, DateStarted = t1.Date,
        t2.DateCompleted
from    tbl t1
outer apply 
        (select  top(1) DateCompleted = t2.Date
        from    tbl t2
        where   t2.Course = t1.Course
            and t2.Status = 'C'
        order by t2.Date) t2
where   t1.Status = 'S'

)

select  cl.School, 
        [Not Completed] = sum(case when cl.DateCompleted is null then 1 else 0 end)
from    cCourseList cl
where   cl.DateStarted <= @InputDate
group by cl.School;
```